# The import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I can't do the following two imports in Selenium 3.4.0

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;  
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
```

My maven dependencies for selenium is as below:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>  
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>  
    <version>3.4.0</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>  
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>  
    <version>3.4.0</version>  
</dependency>
```

I'm getting  error messageslike `The import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType cannot be resolved` in Eclipse

What could be the problem?

Comment: try `right mouse` on project -> `maven` -> `update project` -> `update depedencies`

Comment: @ByeBye i have done it many times, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to include the following imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;  
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
```

You have already added the `org.seleniumhq.selenium` and `org.seleniumhq.selenium` dependencies in the `pom.xml`.

Now, as per the **`Selenium 3.4.0 Documentation` [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp)** as you want to use the **`RemoteWebDriver`** implementation, you still need to download the **`selenium-server-standalone.jar`** from the [**`Selenium Download`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) page and and then either put it into your resources folder and manipulate it through **Runtime** or put it somewhere else and manipulate it via command line.

Comment: I embed the selenium server. The issue is only there for selenium 3.4.0. It works perfectly fine in selenium 3.0.1 (with chrome). I am trying to use geckodriver with the latest selenium version.

Comment: @chenzen So where are you exactly stuck now? Did you download the `selenium-server-standalone.jar`? Can you share your research?

Comment: i solved it by adding the selenium java client to the build path directly.

Answer (score 1):

Add this additional dependency in your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.44.0</version>
</dependency>
```